# Code not assigning to 2D array correctly (C)

Tags: c, arrays

Ok so I'm reading from a text file that looks like this:

```
 3 4
 2 1 1  1
 6 2 1 -7
-2 2 1  7
```

First two number are the number of rows and cols.

Then I read in the matrix and want to assign the values to a 2D array:

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
     FILE *inputFile;
     char ele[256];
     int rows,cols,i,j;


    inputFile = fopen(argv[1], "r" );

    if(inputFile == 0) {
        printf("Can't open '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    fscanf(inputFile, "%d %d", &rows, &cols);
    char *array[rows][cols];




        for ( i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
        {
          for ( j = 0; j < cols; j++ )
          {
             fscanf(inputFile, "%s", ele);
             array[i][j] = ele;          
            }
         }



    for ( i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
      for ( j = 0; j < cols; j++ )
      {
         printf("array[%d][%d] = %s\n", i,j, array[i][j] );
      }
    }

    return 0;

   }
```

First nested loop reads from text file and assign elements to 2D array.

Second loop prints out all the elements of the 2D array.

Right now, my output prints out all the elements of the 2D array but shows them all as 7 (the last element in the text file).

If I print out "ele" in the first loop, it prints out all the elements in the matrix correctly, its just that they're not going into the 2D array 1 by 1.

Disclaimer: I know I'm reading them as chars even though they're ints. That's intentional.

Comment: `char *array[rows][cols]` should be `char array[rows][cols];` (note, `rows` and `cols` are not known at compile time, so this is not a traditional array. An alternative is to dynamically allocate the entire thing by allocating `rows` pointers, then allocating `cols` elements for each pointer.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Doing that gives me a Segmentation failure (removing the pointer *)

Comment: array[i][j] = strdup(ele);

Comment: you really have to make your requirements more clear. You said 'I know I'm reading them as chars even though they're ints' that put everybody on the wrong leg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a number of error (small ones). The primary errors were your `type` mismatches regarding your `format` strings for both `fscaf` and `printf`. You cannot read numeric data with `%s` and hope it will be numeric. To read a signed-character value, you need `%hhd` for both `fscanf` and `printf`. `ele` is type `char` not `char*`. The same with `array`. However, fixing those fixed the read and store of numbers from the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input.  usage:  %s <file>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *inputFile;
    char ele;
    int rows, cols, i, j;


    inputFile = fopen (argv[1], "r");

    if (inputFile == 0) {
        printf ("Can't open '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    fscanf (inputFile, "%d %d", &rows, &cols);
    char array[rows][cols];

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            fscanf (inputFile, "%hhd", &ele);
            array[i][j] = ele;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            printf ("array[%d][%d] = %hhd\n", i, j, array[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/char_array dat/char_array.dat
array[0][0] = 2
array[0][1] = 1
array[0][2] = 1
array[0][3] = 1
array[1][0] = 6
array[1][1] = 2
array[1][2] = 1
array[1][3] = -7
array[2][0] = -2
array[2][1] = 2
array[2][2] = 1
array[2][3] = 7
```

Comment: Works perfect, Thank you. Mind me expanding on the question? This works for this case, but what if my text file has strings of size more than one. Example: array[0][0] = "1010", array[0][1] = "1". And they're seperated by space and/or tabs. How do I edit your code so it works with that?

Comment: The best way to read a file is with **line-oriented** input methods like `fgets` or `getline`. You read a whole line into a buffer. You can then use `strtok` or `strtol` or `sscanf` to get your numbers out of the buffer. (you have more tools to work on the buffer than you do while reading the line). It's all pretty easy, just confusing at first.

Comment: Alright, I'll start googling. Thank you! Would you mind if I private messaged you any future questions instead of making a new post? You seem to be well versed in C syntax unlike myself.

Comment: change the type of ele. A char is too small for an int. Test with 500 in the input file.

Comment: @KHMBH I'm fine with private messages. And the `char` is fine for the numbers between `-128 < n < 127`.

Comment: I don't want to read an int, I just want to read whatever is there in the text file. It could be 1, 0, xyz, 0010 etc etc. Which is why a string is what I want, but apparently there are no strings in C. I thought char element[size] is the same as "string element", but apparently not. Having it as char works for this example though. I'm going to attempt the next level which is reading things like "xyz" and "0110" @PhilipStuyck

Comment: Then this solution does not work at all. As I said, stick to your requirements and make them crystal clear. Everybody here was trying to help with wrong or inaccurate incomplete information.

Comment: No, No, there ARE strings in C. They are called `null-terminated` strings. They just happen to be of type `char` because the `ASCII` values all fall between 0 and `127`. You can use a `char array` as a traditional row x col array, or you can use it as an array of `null-terminated strings`. It's all in how you do it `:p`

Comment: @KHMBH, If you want to read all ints from a file, even if there may be 'stuff' in there and some lines have more ints than others, a jagged array is the easy way to go. I posted this for you to look at [**Read ints from file into jagged array**](http://pastebin.com/L2yajWbr)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Whoops forgot the link lol: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335652/having-some-trouble-coming-up-with-pseudocode-plan-c

Comment: @KHMBH Sure, will take a look, basic approach is the same. You will read a line-at-a-time. Test in read loop if `idx == 0`, if so, read/save heading, otherwise, read line and parse. chars (`line[0-3]`) are 4-digit bitfield, remainder is data. (no need to convert, just use chars) I would parse rest of each line with a pointer. `char *p = line; while (*p) { if (*p == '0' || *p == '1') { do whatever } p++; }` It will be later tomorrow before I have time. I have a couple of post-trial motions to get done from a Feb. trial, but then I'll take a closer look.

Comment: @KHMBH This will get you started. [**C filter wiretest data, dynamic arrays, structs**](http://pastebin.com/DXhESzAj) More work is needed to get the automatic selection of 4 rows for all tests (currently solves for 6 [5 if you though out 1]). I didn't have time to mess with it further, but you can use what is there. It will be a day or two before I have more time. Just compile it and give your data filename as the first argument.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, you're assigning every element in `array` (each of which is a pointer-to-`char`) the address of `ele[0]`, which is why they're all printing out as the last string you read into `ele`.  They're all pointing to the same string.

**EDIT:** Misunderstood what you were getting at, rephrased my reply.  Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: how do i fix that then? I've been googling for hours, nothing of worth.

Comment: You could allocate a new string for each array element with `strdup` as @Philip-Stuyck mentions below, or make `array` an array of `int`s and fill it with `array[i][j] = atoi(ele);` instead.  Why are you working with strings in the matrix, anyway?

Comment: upvoted because it points to the essence of the problem in the source.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this :

```
array[i][j] = ele;
```

do this :

```
array[i][j] = strdup(ele);
```

strdup allocates memory so at the end of the program you have to release that memory.
I am assuming you want to keep using string, ie char arrays to store the values.
If this is not a requirement you can have a different solution that does not need strdup.

Comment: Oh no, you just `null-terminated` his numeric array entries.

Comment: At this point it is a bit unclear what the requirements are. You changed the ele type, should I now create a comment : 'oh no you changed the type of ele' ?

Comment: apparently that was not the problem. ;-)

Comment: apparently it is a problem. the OP wants strings!